# If the set of the output of a computable function is finite, is the sequence periodic eventually?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability-theory

$$f:N \rightarrow B,\space B\subset N $$ and $B$ is finite, $S$ is the sequence constructed by $f(1),f(2)\cdots f(i)\cdots $.
 Now, if $f$ is a computable function,is $S$ eventually periodic?

Update: Secondly, if the computable  function is computable in p time, is the $S$ eventually periodic? Or, under which computational complexity of the computable functions is $S$ eventually periodic?or such a computational complexity condition of computable function does not exist?
Any reference is welcome.

Thirdly, what computational complexity of computable functions is the boundary under or above which the $S$ is eventually periodic or is not periodic ultimately?

Comment: Not necessarily.  There are square-free words on three symbols which show the possibility that no repetition occurs.  A simple example is the parity of the number of one's in the binary expansion of a number.  Gerhard "Not Intending To Repeat Myself" Paseman, 2016.11.09.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I cann't understand what you are talking about, sorry

Comment: See here for another example (there are many): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_word

Comment: Take two symbols a and b. the sequence  a,b,a,a,b,a,a,a,b,a,a,a,a and so forth, where you repeat a with increasing multiplicity, is computable, but not periodic.

Comment: Examples of computable sequences: 3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,... and 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 1,0,  1,1, 1,2, 1,3, ..., 1,9,  2,0,  2,1, 2,2, ...

Comment: @Goldstern Thank you for you example, very interesting1

Comment: This question is better suited for cs.stackexchange.com, as it is not research-level.

Comment: @AndrejBauer thank you. Could you answer the third question? I really need an answer.

Comment: @ChristianRemling any link between spectral and this kind of question?

Comment: Think of the decimal digits of (computable) irrational number. If $f_a(i)$ is the ith digit of irrational number $a$, then your $B$ is finite($|B|=10$) but the sequence is not periodic by definition.

Comment: Thank you, everybody,but please try answer the third question which is not trivial.

Comment: I think you can capture all periodic functions in linear time because you can revert it to modulo operation. On the other hand you can define constant time function that is not periodic just by printing the first digit of the input number.

Comment: I had known how to solve the problem yesterday, since busy and sleeping, I have not replied, anyway thank you ,everyone discussing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the 2nd question, the set of output sequences of an [autonomous finite automaton](https://books.google.com/books?id=s58EXPW6B6sC&pg=PA215&lpg=PA215&dq=output%20of%20finite%20automaton%20periodic&source=bl&ots=Liwgupg94l&sig=IKEczqfQqDhR6QZ7-CfG4YV57FE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUz8Ody53QAhWIi1QKHeEwB8UQ6AEIIzAB) consists of ultimately periodic sequences.